# How send Https request with OAuth 1.0 authentication in Flutter

Tags: flutter, http, https, dio, pub.dev

I was trying DIO HTTP packages but not find any way dto send request with OAuth 1.0.
There is a package [oauth1](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth1) but I could not understand it. please tell me any solution I want to use it in woocommerce api.